# Show reputation while hovering names in the hold/close notification

Tags: feature-request, reputation

When the usernames of question and answer authors are displayed, reputation information is displayed in the name plate:

> [image]

Similarly, when a comment is left, reputation information can be viewed by hovering over the author's name:

> [image]

However, no such information is available when usernames are displayed in hold/close notifications:

> [image]

When a question is closed, the OP often wants to know why and by whom. Names alone are meaningless to many users (especially new ones). If the reputation of the closers is displayed, it may serve to reinforce the credibility of the action. Is there a specific reason that the reputation is not displayed here? If not, can we consider adding it?

Comment: Is the amount of reputation that a person has (above the required reputation for closing privileges) relevant to the closing of a question?  One click gets you to his profile page, where his stats are displayed in detail.

Comment: It is relevant insomuch as it gives credibility to the close action. High-rep users are expected to understand how the site works, so seeing that Jon Skeet closed the question may help to calm the OP's qualms that the close was unacceptable. (I assume that the moderator diamond is shown in those notifications for the same reason, especially when a moderator closes before five votes are cast.) While you are right that one click gets you to the profile page, we show the rep easier elsewhere; why not here? Also consider that there are potentially five clicks involved: one for each close-voter.